# How to display random posts in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

How to display random posts for each category when the url style like : `http://www.whatever.com/category/all-english/poetry/`, so each time I click the category link it display different posts

I tried this :

```
$cat=get_query_var( 'cat' );
query_posts('cat=$cat&orderby=rand');
if (have_posts()) : 
    if ( $is_top_single ) $GLOBALS['more'] = false; //important
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

but the result is not true, it display random posts for all categories !

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how to use [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts). You can edit your `archive.php` or `category.php` as follows:

```
query_posts(array(
    'showposts' => 6,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'category_name' => 'News' //You can insert any category name
));
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Comment: how to get the current category name ( dynamic )

Comment: http://www.mrphpguru.com/blog/2011/04/14/get-current-category-name-wp/ Also learn how to accept answers, that way you can get  better responses.